# When would I want to be somebody's friend?

Tags: civilization-5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In Civ 5, are Declarations of Friendship worth it?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14828/in-civ-5-are-declarations-of-friendship-worth-it)

Being somebody's friend is good because it gets you better trade agreements. Super. But it's also dangerous, as I've experienced too many times, because if my friend ever find a reason to denounce me then suddenly *everyone* hates me. Because of this I rarely accept friendship requests any more, and I never offer them myself.

Plus, friends tend to ask for favors once in a while. :(

My question is, **in which situations would I want to be somebody's friend?** Should I try to make friends with warmongering civs that wouldn't frown upon *my* warmongering? Should I try to become friends with far-away civilizations that are unlikely to find any reason to denounce me? Should I prefer to be friends with a stronger civilization, or a weaker one? etc.

Comment: I think the idea is to make friends with civilizations that play the game the same way you do.

Comment: @Wipqozn but are you sure they won't denounce me because we try to win the same way (there's even a specific "dislike" reason for that)?

Comment: Ah yes you have a good point. I forgot about that.

Comment: Similar to http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14828/in-civ-5-are-declarations-of-friendship-worth-it

Comment: Perhaps a title change to: "Why would I want to be anybody's friend?"

Comment: @Raven I understand the "why", though, friendship does have its advantages... it's just unclear to me under what situation is it worth the disadvantages.

Comment: @RavenDreamer: How about a title change to "Why can't I have any friends? :(" ;)

Comment: @bwarner I would go so far as to say this question is a duplicate.

Comment: Are you talking about allying with city states, other civs, or both?

Comment: @Wipq It kind of seems that way to me, but there are no close votes yet, so I figured I must be missing something.

Comment: @bwarner There will never be close votes if people wait on others. Remember that if no one agrees, then the close vote will harmlessly age away, so don't be afraid to cast the first vote.

Comment: @Kyle I'm talking about other civilizations

Comment: The obvious answer would be, "the day after he wins the lottery"